# How to enable group access token on GitLab ultimate trial version?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I'm using the GitLab Ultimate trial version and would like to have a group access token created however when I go to Settings -> Access Token on my group I get this below message (refer to screenshot):-

```
Group access token creation is disabled in this group. You can enable group access token creation in group settings.
```

It seems like I need to enable the group access token settings first however I do not see any option under General of Settings to get this done. Could someone please assist on this?
[image]

[Added screenshot]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html) (emphasis mine):

> You can use group access tokens:
>
> - On GitLab SaaS: If you have the Premium or Ultimate license tier. **Group access tokens are not available with a trial license**.
> - On self-managed instances: With any license tier. If you have the Free tier:
>   [...]

---

If you're eligible for group access tokens, you will find them at `[Group Page] -> Settings -> General > "Permissions and group features"`:

[image: pic of permissions and group features]

Comment: I guess this option is not there for the Ultimate edition of Gitlab as I do not see any such checkbox (refer updated query with screenshot). One has to be a paid user

Comment: We are on the free self-hosted tier, what type of hosting are you using? @vinod827

Comment: @vinod827 updated the answer, should be clear now

Comment: As an aside: I find it a bit weird that they hide the option outright instead of just disabling it. I found the docs by just clicking on the link on the settings page, which isn't visible when you don't have access to the feature...